# How to display images in Android and change it by swipe right/left?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to add an introduction to my Android application, to inform the user about how the app works. This intro will be displayed only, if the preferred settings intro will be false. So in this intro, there will be 3 images and at the end, there will be a page, with some text and two buttons, to enable the user to access the application, by making a login. The change between each image, will be made with a swipe movement, (so right to left +, left to right -). How Can I do ?

Comment: See this tutorial on [Android Hive](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/)

Comment: Thank you ! Do you suggest to follow the Creating Fullscreen Image Slider code ? What about the fact that the last page, will be made with the standard tool in Eclipse (so with TextArea, Buttons etc..) a not just a simple image ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done via the use of Fragments and ViewPager and FragmentPagerAdapter. Look at this documentation:

FragmentPagerAdapter: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html

ViewPager:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

You can have one fragment that is instantiated based on the id in the ViewPager, and that id will indicate which image to show in your image fragment. So for three images, you instantiate a new fragment that sets the image in the fragment based on the current page in the FragmentPagerAdapter. The second fragment can be one for the login buttons and text you want at the end.

Ex for adapter defined in your FragmentActivity (or AppCompatActivity)

```
    public class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_ITEMS;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            if(position < 3)
                return ImageFragment.newInstance(position);
            else
                return new LoginFragment();
        }
}
```

Ex for the image fragment for the various images in your introduction:

```
public static class ImageFragment extends Fragment{
    private int mPosition;

    public ImageFragment(){
    }

    public static ImageFragment newInstance(int pos){
        ImageFragment frag = new ImageFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("pos", pos);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mPosition = getArguments().getInt("pos");

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image, container, false);
            ImageView backgroundView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.background_image);
            switch(mPosition){
                case 0:
                    //set background view image 1
                case 1:
                    //set background view image 2
                default:
                    //set background view image 3
            }
            return v;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you ! It is very clear. The only think I haven't understand, in which activity should I wrote this code.

Comment: Write this is in your splash screen activity (the adapter and view pager live there) you essentially swap out fragments in your view pager

Comment: What is R.layout.fragment_image and R.id.background_image ?

Comment: Those are the XML defined id / layouts for your fragments. The R.layout.fragment_image is going to be the name of your XML file for the fragment's layout (the fragment for images in your splash screen activity). This means yo need to create a layout called fragment_image.xml or some other name that is just a place holder. And the R.id.background_image is the id of the ImageView or FrameLayout you are using to hold the background image within that said fragment. You only need 1 layout defined and use it differently for each of the three image fragments you wanted for the splash screen

Comment: Thank you for your more comment, but I'm not able to do that. Can yo edit your response, with all the code, with the WelcomeActivity ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a ViewPager. Check out this tutorial from the Developer Guide

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

If you want to add functionality to each of these pages instead of having just images then perhaps you can implement a fragmentStatePagerAdapter and then put all the functionality in each fragment. Here is a tutorial to implement one.

http://www.truiton.com/2013/05/android-fragmentstatepageradapter-example/

Answer (score 1):

I think we can do it by using recycler view itself.
Using PagerSnapHelper layout manager in recycler view, we can implement swipe to change images.

```
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,
            LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));

    // add pager behavior
    PagerSnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
    snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```