# Trying to display different Images as the user swipes - Android Development

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am relatively new to Android Development and was hoping I could get some help here. I have added two fragments to one page. The top fragment is an ImageView and the bottom is just random buttons and text. I am trying to display different images in the top fragment (the ImageView) as the user swipes left or right on the screen. I based my code off this other : [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30245993/how-to-display-images-in-android-and-change-it-by-swipe-right-left). I however keep receiving the error below when I try to run it. I pasted what I believe to be the relevant code below the error. Please let me know if I need to post additional code! Thank you.

> 12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.newmoney.night_life_now, PID: 3996
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.newmoney.night_life_now/com.newmoney.night_life_now.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class fragment
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class fragment
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:770)
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:933)
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.newmoney.night_life_now.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758) 
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448) 
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942) 
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194) 
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.os.Bundle.getInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.newmoney.night_life_now.Picture_Section_Fragment.onCreate(Picture_Section_Fragment.java:43)
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1766)
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:917)
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1116)
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1218)
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2170)
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:300)
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.callActivityOnCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:842)
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.callActivityOnCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:34)
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:830)
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:732)
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:933) 
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) 
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249) 
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106) 
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.newmoney.night_life_now.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27) 
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289) 
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646) 
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758) 
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448) 
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942) 
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
>   12-01 21:48:08.686 3996-3996/com.newmoney.night_life_now E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
// For this example, only two pages
static final int NUM_ITEMS = 3;
ViewPager mPager;
SlidePagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button clickButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getDirectionsButton);
    clickButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Get Directions Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    /* Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter. */
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new SlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

}

/* PagerAdapter class */
public class SlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public SlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        /*
         * IMPORTANT: This is the point. We create a RootFragment acting as
         * a container for other fragments
         */
        if (position == 0) {
            Log.w("MainAct", "pos0");
            return new Picture_Section_Fragment().newInstance(position);
        } else {
            Log.w("MainAct", "pos1");
            return new Picture_Section_Fragment().newInstance(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }
}
```

}

```
public class Picture_Section_Fragment extends Fragment{
private int mPosition;
private ViewPager mPager;
private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

public static Picture_Section_Fragment newInstance(int pos){
    Picture_Section_Fragment frag = new Picture_Section_Fragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("pos", pos);
    frag.setArguments(args);
    return frag;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mPosition = getArguments().getInt("pos");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String urlString = null;
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.picture_section_fragment, container, false);   // this is what layout to use for fragment
    //String urlString = "http://hdwallpapers.thenewstrack.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/New-York-City-Hd-Wallpaper-Free-Download-3.jpg";
    //new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.barclubImages)).execute(urlString);

    //mPosition = getArguments().getInt("pos");

    switch(mPosition){
        case 0:
            Log.w("PicSecFrag", "Case0");
            urlString = "http://hdwallpapers.thenewstrack.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/New-York-City-Hd-Wallpaper-Free-Download-3.jpg";
            new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.barclubImages)).execute(urlString);
            break;
        case 1:
            urlString = "http://7-themes.com/data_images/out/60/6975166-beach-hd-wallpaper-6468.jpg";
            new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.barclubImages)).execute(urlString);
            break;
        default:
            urlString = "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-9VWTk3LsUrU/UAe8GnV6hWI/AAAAAAAAHCw/ATOzf-5b230/s1600/Hdhut.blogspot.com+(12).jpg";
            new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.barclubImages)).execute(urlString);
    }

    return view;
}

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

These two lines in the stacktrace tell us the problem:

> InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class fragment
>
> NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.os.Bundle.getInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

The inflation is failing because you've apparently defined a static `Picture_Section_Fragment` in the `activity_main` layout XML. When the Fragment is loaded from a layout, you never have a chance to set arguments on it, so `getArguments()` is returning null in `onCreate()`, and throwing the `NullPointerException` when you try to call `getInt()` on it. If you must set arguments on the Fragments, you can't statically define them in the layout. They must be loaded dynamically, like in the `PagerAdapter`. You can either remove the Fragment(s) from the layout file, or pass the necessary data another way; for example, through a public method.

Additionally, `Picture_Section_Fragment`'s `newInstance()` method is `static`, meaning that it's meant to be called on the class itself, rather than an instance of it. In `SlidePagerAdapter`, you're instantiating the Fragment with `new`, then calling `newInstance()` on the newly created instance, which then creates another new instance, and returns that one, discarding the one created with `new`. So you're effectively creating an intermediate instance that you don't really need. Change the relevant lines in `SlidePagerAdapter` as follows:

```
return Picture_Section_Fragment.newInstance(position);
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I made that fix but still get the following (similar) stack trace

Comment: Stack Trace: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.os.Bundle.getInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: Code Snippet to show I made the change `
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
   /*
    * IMPORTANT: This is the point. We create a RootFragment acting as
    * a container for other fragments
    */
            if (position == 0) {
                Log.w("MainAct", "pos0");
                //return new Picture_Section_Fragment().newInstance(position);
                return Picture_Section_Fragment.newInstance(position);
            } else {
                Log.w("MainAct", "pos1");
                return Picture_Section_Fragment.newInstance(position);
            }
        }`

Comment: Thank you! I haven't gotten the chance to get back to this as i've been swamped with work. But this will def help me this weekend!